# Can't I overwrite the then() function of Promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to collecting errors thrown in ES6 Promise.

I thought about a way to do so is to overwrite the `Promise.prototype.then` function. Here is my code:

```js
let originalThen = Promise.prototype.then;
Promise.prototype.then = function(onResolved, onRejected) {
    return originalThen.call(this, onResolved, onRejected).catch(error => {
        console.log(`upload the error to server: ${ error }`);
        throw error;
    })
}
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('something');
})
.then(value => {
    // I think this error should be caught and upload to server.
    throw new Error('test error')
}).catch(error => {
    //the previous error should also be caught here.
    console.log('caught error in catch()')
})
```

When I run this code in Firefox, I got a `"too much recursion"` error. The log statement `"upload the error to server"` was executed over and over again! But I did nothing recursive in my code. What happened?

Comment: I mean, the recursion is there. You're calling a promise that resolves into calling it self again just to verify a catch?

Comment: I'm going to give you only one advise -- don't override then. there'are no real cases when you would need to override it.

Comment: Why would you do this? You can use multiple `.catch()` clauses inside a promise chain. And the second parameter to `.then()` is the onError handler, as if there was a .catch() after it. So it looks a bit you're trying to implement how promises already work.

Comment: I did this because I want to automatically upload the error in _every_ Promise instance to server.  If I don't do this, I will have to write a additional `catch` statement to upload the error every time I use Promise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.catch(onReject)` is just syntactic sugar for `.then(undefined, onReject)`, the `catch` method is just a wrapper that calls `then`. Calling it from within your overwritten `then` does cause (infinite) recursion.

Instead, you need to use `originalThen` to catch the rejection:

```
let originalThen = Promise.prototype.then;
Promise.prototype.then = function(onResolved, onRejected) {
    return originalThen.call(originalThen.call(this, onResolved, onRejected), undefined, error => {
        console.log(`upload the error to server: ${ error }`);
        throw error;
    });
}
```

---

That said, I think overwriting `then` is a bad idea.

> I am trying to collecting errors thrown in ES6 Promise.

To do that, you better collect errors through [`unhandledrejection` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/unhandledrejection_event). Many of your promise chains will use errors on purpose and handle them later locally - you only want to log unexpected errors to your server.